# How do I get rid of Ubuntu shortcuts in Unity 13.10 (Intellij...)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, intellij-idea, ubuntu-13.10

I want to change Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) shortcuts. For example, I want to get rid of <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd>. Well, I tried everything.

The last thing I tried was `ccsm` and removed any reference to <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd>. However, still when I click <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> it opens the search bar.

I also tried `gconf-editor`, looked for any reference of that keyboard shortcut, and removed it, but nothing helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt Left</kbd> is associated to the search bar, so you trigger it when doing <kbd>Alt L.</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

That's the shortcut you want to change/remove through Ubuntu's system settings/keyboard/Shortcut window.

Comment: the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> is now disabled with the method you suggested looks like indeed it did some change but `Alt+F1` still toggles highlighting of top left unity button :/

Comment: after one day things look better (although I logged out previously) maybe a restart to my ubuntu helped for keys to catch on now ALT does not start ubuntu menu.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 12.04, I had to open the `CompizConfig Settings Manager` (CSSM), go to the `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`, the `Behaviour` tab and deactivate the `Key to put keyboard-focus on launcher` which was predefined as `Alt-F1`.

Comment: just disabled via ccsm "Key to give keyboard-focus to the laucher" but it still activates it :(

Comment: Sorry, I have no 13.10 to try it on.  This works for my 12.04.

Comment: This works well for 16.04.